# Integrating $I_{2n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{dx}{\cos^{2n}x}$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to prove that if
$$I_{2n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\cos^{2n}x} dx $$ 
Then, for every $n\geq{1}$,

$$I_{2n}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2n-1}+\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}I_{2n-2}$$

I have tried to integrate by parts without any results, using $u=x$ and $\displaystyle v=\frac{1}{\cos^{2n}x}$.

I am studying an introductory calculus course and I am pretty sure I should be able to solve this problem integrating by parts.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?p=47972 OR https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/integral-sec-n-x-dx-722738

Answer (score 2):

By substituting $x=\arctan t$ we have

$$ I_{2n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(\frac{1}{1+t^2})^n}=\int_{0}^{1}(1+t^2)^{n-1}\,dt \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that
$$I_{2n+2} = I_{2n}+\int_{0}^{1}t\cdot t(1+t^2)^{n-1}\,dt\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}I_{2n}+\left[t\cdot\frac{(1+t^2)^{n}}{2n}\right]_{0}^{1}-\frac{1}{2n}I_{2n+2}\tag{2} $$
where $\text{IBP}$ stands for *integration by parts*. The claim readily follows from rearranging the LHS and RHS of $(2)$. By applying the binomial theorem to the RHS of $(1)$ we also have

$$ I_{2n+2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1} \tag{3}$$
and since $\int_{0}^{1}(1-t^2)^k\,dt = \frac{4^k}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}}$ by $(1+t^2)=2-(1-t^2)$...
$$ I_{2n+2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}\frac{4^k(-1)^k}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}}=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-2)^k\binom{n}{k}}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite this as $$I_{2n} = \int_0^{\pi/4} \sec^2 x \cdot \sec^{2n-2}x \, \mathrm{d}x = I_{2n} =  \bigg[\sec^{2n} x\bigg]_0^{\pi/4} - (2n-2)\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^{2n-2}x \tan^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

via IBP with $u = \sec^{2n-2} x \implies \frac{du}{dx} = (2n-2) \tan x \sec^{2n-2} x$ and $\mathrm{d}v = \sec^2 x$. Now recalling that $1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2$ gives $$I_{2n} = 2^n-1-(2n-2)I_{2n} +(2n-2)I_{2n-2} $$

and rearranging gives

$$(2n-1)I_{2n} = 2^n - 1 -  (2n-2)I_{2n-2}.$$